# Scroll to latest added element in *ngFor loop in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have ngFor loop rendering HTML div. The list behind this loop is dynamic, meaning that the page displays a button allowing to add or remove an element from the list.
What I would like to achieve, it's to scroll the browser view to the latest element added when the user click to add a new element in the list.

The scrollToView(true) doesn't work as the element is not yet rendered by the *ngFor loop as soon as I pass into my javascript function that adds a new element.

The HTML page

```
<div class="container"><div class="row">

<div *ngIf="selection.length <= 0" class="align-sm-right">
  <button id="add-selection-default" class="btn app-btn-primary anim-bg"
          (click)="add()">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i><span>Add</span></button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let sel of selection; let index = index; let last = last">

  <div id="{{'id' + index}}" class="form-sub-section">
  </div>

</div>
```

The method call to add a document

```
  add() {
this.selection.push({});

// code to scroll to newly added element
```

}

Is there some solutions using onCreate or something else to detect when an element is added and rendered and then scroll to this specific element ?

Thanks,
Regards,

Comment: Where is the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I used [ng2-page-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll) like this

```
constructor(
  private pageScroll: PageScrollService,
) {
  PageScrollConfig.defaultDuration = 500;
  PageScrollConfig.defaultEasingLogic = {
    ease: (t: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): number => {
      // ease-in-out easing function
      if (t === 0) { return b; }
      if (t === d) { return b + c; }
      if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) { return c / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b; }
      return c / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
    }
  };
}
```

And when you want to go to a location in the page, use

```
this.pageScroll.start(PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(document, '#yourLocationId'));
```